# Can Notification Center Observe Value Change Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, observers

Is something like this possible?

Observe `SearchUtil().getSearchList().count` so whenever the count changes or equals to a specific int value(`SearchUtil().getSearchList().count == 0`) run `@objc func OnAppBecameActive()`

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(OnAppBecameActive), name: SearchUtil().getSearchList().count, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this. The thing you want to observe needs to be a property, not the outcome of an expression. If this is (or can be) an NSObject, you can use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA). If not, you can make this a [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) property and set up a pipeline that processes each change.